# Accessing a java.util.Calendar field in EL

Tags: jsf-2, calendar, el

We have to display the year field on the Facelets page.

```
<h:outputText value="#{dateTOloginDate.get(Calendar.YEAR)}"/>
```

This always returns a 1 and not the year value. How can I achieve it?

Comment: I posted code but did not format it. Anyways I have found the issue. Instead of get(Calendar.YEAR), we should use get(1).

Answer (score 2):

The [`Calendar.YEAR`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#YEAR) is a constant field value. Constant field values are by default not available in EL scope at all. Hardcoded constant values do however work, as you encountered yourself.

There are several ways to achieve this in a more clean manner:

1. Use [`<f:convertDateTime>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/convertDateTime.html) instead. You'll only need to get the [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) instance by [`Calendar#getTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime%28%29).

   ```html
   <h:outputText value="#{dateTOloginDate.time}">
       <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy" />
   </h:outputText>
   ```
2. Use [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) [`<o:importConstants>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/importConstants). It allows you to import the constant field values of a given type into the EL scope. This way you'll be able to use exactly the intented syntax.

   ```html
   <o:importConstants type="java.util.Calendar" />
   ...
   <h:outputText value="#{dateTOloginDate.get(Calendar.YEAR)}" />
   ```

   Only, this is IMO an extreme use case. I'd personally prefer the `<f:convertDateTime>` way. It would also be more ideal if you just use `java.util.Date` instead of the clumsy `java.util.Calendar`. I don't see how it's beneficial to have a `java.util.Calendar` as model value type.